# Setup class and import properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I have a Python script called `DBWriter.py` and within it there is a class `DBWriter`. Then, I have a another class called `DBManager` in `DBManager.py` which also has a main.

All I want to do is import (from the package that all of the scripts/classes are in which is `dbmanagement`) is import `DBWriter` in order to create an object of it.

Every time I try:

```
from dbmanagement import DBWriter
```

and then simply do

```
dbW = DBWriter('/dir/to/db')
```

I get a

> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable.

I am getting very frustrated even though this is - hopefully - quite simplistic.

Comment: I have even looked at a lot of other things on stack overflow, and maybe I didn't look at the right ones, but no amount of import variations seemed to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `DBWriter` is the *module* not the class. If I understood correctly you probably need something like:

```
dbW = DBWriter.DBWriter('/dir/to/db')
```

to access the object `DBWriter` inside your `DBWriter` module.

Or as an alternative, you can just import the class itself (and not the entire module), with:

```
from dbmanagement.DBWriter import DBWriter
```

Answer (score 0):

## Answer to my own question:

Luckily, Eclipse helped me out.

It's `from dbmanagement.DBWriter import DBWriter`. A little redundant, but hopefully this helps someone.

Where dbmanagement is the package name, DBWriter is the **module** name **as well as** the **class** name

Comment: It's not redundant, you're directly importing the class that is in the module.